# What's the difference between a global variable and a 'window.variable' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, attributes, scope

I'm reading the [Backbone.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backbone.js) documents and am seeing a lot of code that assigns attributes to the *window* object:

```
window.something = "whatever";
```

What's the difference between calling this code, and just assigning the variable and creating a global variable, like this:

```
something = "whatever";
```

I assume there is some kind of scope difference, and/or object ownership difference (*window* being the owner vs. not), but I am interested in the detail between the two and why I would use *window* vs. not use it.

Comment: This isn't really related to your particular case, but remember that Javascript doesn't *have* to run in a browser, so window doesn't *have* to be defined.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

No difference. They both have the same effect (In the browser, where `window` is the global context<sup>1</sup>).

- `window.foo = "bar"` sets the property `foo` on `window`.
- `foo = "bar"` indicates either **a typo** or intentionally global.

Since I have to double check whether it's a typo or not, I personally find it more **readable** to set `window.foo` directly.

Also, in ES5 strict mode, `foo = "bar"` is an illegal assignment because `foo` is not declared and will throw a `Error`.

**Edit:**

As noted in the comments, `foo = "bar"` will look all the way up the scope chain for the variable `foo` and re-assign it with `"bar"` if it's found. If it's not found, it will create a new global variable.

Also with `window.foo = "bar"` you're just assigning a property to an object, which can be deleted using `delete window.foo`.

In ES5 strict mode it is *invalid* to `delete` a variable.

---

<sup>1</sup> In other environments, such as node.js and Web Workers, there may be another name for the global object and `window` may not exist at all. Node.js uses `global` and Web Workers use `self`.

Comment: As an aside, you can delete window.foo but not a global foo defined with var.

Comment: There is a difference. `window.foo = bar;` sets foo on the window object. `foo = bar;` searches up the scope chain till it finds `foo`, which may end up being the global object, but not always.

Comment: @kennebec I believe that's browser specific.

Comment: @Raynos: The difference in being able to delete is not really browser-specific. According to the ECMAScript spec and assuming `window` is the global object, the behaviour @kennebec describes is correct. Older versions of IE don't conform, however.

Comment: @TimDown It's not supposed to be browser specific but it is. I agree however that the ES spec says you can delete properties.

Answer (score 13):

They both kind of do the same thing. But by accessing a *window* property, you know for sure that you're accessing a global variable no matter what scope you're in.

For example:

```
globalVar = "smth";
function(){
    var globalVar = 2;
    alert(globalVar); // Points to the current scope globalVar
    alert(window.globalVar); // Points to the original globalVar
}
```

In other words, If you want to work with globals, it's somewhat safer to access them via their container: `window.variable`

Answer (score 7):

The key, as [Raynos alluded to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349232/whats-the-difference-between-a-global-variable-and-a-window-variable-in-javas/6349260#6349260), is that it's set explicitly on the *window* object. In the browser, the global object is the same as the *window* object but in other environments (e.g., Node.js, or perhaps running in a web view of some sort on a mobile device), it may not.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that `window.foo = bar;` cannot be intercepted by refactoring done later.
Using `foo = bar;` means that if, at a later date, the code is moved into a closure where `var foo` has been defined, it will no longer set it on the global object.

Answer (score 2):

*Adding one more point:*

If you refer an **undeclared variable** directly (without using - **window** or **typeof**) then you will get a variable is not defined **error**.

Examples:

```
// var unDecVariable

if (unDecVariable != null) // Error: unDecVariable is not defined
{
    // do something
}

if (window.unDecVariable != null) // No Error
{
    // do something
}

if (typeof unDecVariable != 'undefined' && unDecVariable != null) // Alternative way
{
    // do something
}
```