# Javascript global variable type change

Tags: javascript, types

In Javascript, I can assign a global variable in different data types in different function scope. For example:

```
var a = 1;
function foo(){
  a = a + 10;  //a is number in foo
}

function bar(){
  a = a + "hello";  //a is string in bar
  foo();  //a is string in foo now
}
foo();
bar();
```

My example is just a simple demo and I believe most Javascript programmers won't write it. However, is there any practical usage for such dynamic feature that global variable changes its data type in different functions?

Comment: dynamic typing can be useful, but there's a big debate about this topic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_and_dynamic_type_checking_in_practice

Comment: Thanks @DougT. for your information. But I still want to know is there a real or practical usage in my case even that I see most JavaScript programmers won't do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic typing allows you to do stuff like this :

```
var a = false;    
if(need to show msg 1){a="message 1"};
if(need to show msg 2){a="message 2"};     
if(a){display(a);}
```

The example is not very good, but the idea is that you can use the same variable as a condition and content, or as an array element and as an error message if what you are looking for is not in the array,...

By the way, when you write `a = 1`, it is practically equivalent to `window.a = 1`; global variables can be considered as properties of the window object (.[see here for precisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349232/whats-the-difference-between-a-global-var-and-a-window-variable-in-javascript)).

So when you write `a = a + "hello";`, a becomes a string everywhere and not just 'in foo'.

Answer (score 0):

1. `var a = 1; //global variable`
2. In `foo()` if (1) is defined

`function foo(){
          a; //In this case a will be global variable and a = 1
        }
    function foo(){
      var a;  //In this case a will be private variable, a = undefined but global varibale a not change
    }`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to do. With Javascript, global variables that are manipulated into different types can be dangerous if you're using a lot of callbacks. Callbacks functions triggering a lot (of course asynchronously) and manipulating a global variable can make it so you end up reading the wrong data in one or more callback functions and an unexpected result will follow deviating from your code's intention.