# Javascript - Share Variables over different <script> tags

Tags: javascript, scope, global, var

I have one `test.html` file with two `<script>` tags. I need to share a variable from one to another..

Sample code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var test = false;

  function testing() {
    test = true;
    alert('I am inside..');
  }

  testing();
</script>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (test == true) {
    alert('working');
  } else {
    alert('failed');
  }
</script>
```

The output is always:

> I am inside..
>
> failed

I also tried to use the `window` class but it doesn't matter.. (`window.test`)

What I have to do to get the 'working' alert?

Thanks if anyone can help me. I saw some similar questions, but the answers wasn't a solution for me.

**EDIT:**

The original code (simplified):

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="detectblocker.js"></script>
    <!-- GitHub: https://github.com/sitexw/BlockAdBlock/ -->
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var blocker = false;

        function adBlockDetected() {
            blocker = true;
            alert('inside');
        }

        if(typeof blockAdBlock === 'undefined') {
            adBlockDetected();
        } else {
            blockAdBlock.onDetected(adBlockDetected);
        }

        blockAdBlock.setOption({
            checkOnLoad: true,
            resetOnEnd: true
        });
    </script>
    <div class="header">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="content_body">
        <div class="requirs">
            <ul>
                ...
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    if (blocker == true) {
                        document.write("<li>enabled!</li>")
                    } else {
                        document.write("<li>disabled!</li>")
                    }
                </script>
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

The output is an `alert()` "inside" and the `<li>` "disabled".. (Blocker is enabled..).
The only difference I can see is on the end of the first `<script>` tag:

```
blockAdBlock.setOption({
    checkOnLoad: true,
    resetOnEnd: true
});
```

So why the snippet is working and my code not? Confusing...

Comment: I converted your snippet to a live demo and … it works. Whatever the problem is, you haven't exposed it in your question.

Comment: You could use localStorage. Although I don't feel like it's an elegant solution to your problem.

Comment: @user2085143 — localStorage is used for sharing data between different pages (or loads of the same page). It isn't for sharing data between different scripts on the same page.

Comment: But it would work would it not?

Comment: @Quentin well, that makes my answer irrelevant :) I should have edited OP's post instead (although it makes his problem disappear, so "conflicts with author's intent"?

Comment: @xShirase — The problem never appeared in the first place. The edit just highlights that it never appeared.

Comment: i copied that code and tried .That works perfect .where is the issue?

Comment: @Quentin ... 0.o I will look again.. didn't try the sample snippet. I will give an update later.

Comment: @13loodH4t you didn't happen to use async or defer on any of the script tags? that would explain it, maybe...

Comment: @Quentin I've updated my code.. but I can't see a solution?! -.-

Comment: @xShirase I don't know what you mean.. take a look with the code update now.. is that what you mean?

Comment: @13loodH4t — After your edit … it still outputs "enabled" so you still don't seem to have provided a [mcve]

Comment: It still works like that, your scripts will always be loading in a blocking manner. I suspect that the function you use to detect an adblocker is asynchronous, and therefore lets the other scripts execute before it returns a result look for something that says `dosomething( args, function(){...`

Comment: If you hit the `else` branch of `if(typeof blockAdBlock === 'undefined')` and  `blockAdBlock.onDetected` is asyncronous (which it sounds like it is) then this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). Since you haven't provided a [mcve] it isn't possible to tell for sure though.

Comment: @xShirase How do I force the detect function to wait for response before going on?

Comment: @Quentin, what's the procedure to reflag a question that went from unclear to duplicate?

Comment: @13loodH4t — the point of `on...` functions is that they do cause the function you pass to them to wait. It's the second script element (which has no functions at all) that isn't waiting.

Comment: @xShirase — Let someone else do it. Or *maybe* hit the Flag and ask a moderator to intervene.

Comment: @Quentin, that was just a theoretical question, it's still offtopic as there's no MCVE :p

Comment: I think @xShirase is right. The second script tag gets executed before the test var has changed..

Answer (score 2):

If you do not use `var` before a variable it becomes a global variable like

```
test = true;
```

The variable `test` will be true during the page and also in your next scripts and functions.

Try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var test = false;

      function testing() {
        var test = true;
        alert('I am inside..');
      }

      testing();
    </script>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if (test == true) {
        alert('working');
      } else {
        alert('failed');
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: It's not working.. as `var` create a new variable scope inside the function.

Comment: "if you do not use var before a variable it become's as an global variable" — `test` **needs** to be a global variable for it to be read in the second script element!

Comment: @alifallahi — I just explained that in my last comment.

Comment: test has false value, just inside testing() it becomes true. so near the end because of else the last alert will show failed

Comment: @alifallahi — No. `test` has a false value. Then inside `testing` you create a **different** variable, also called `test` and assign `true` to that. The function ends and the second `test` variable goes out of scope. Then the second script reads the original, global, variable (which is still `false`).

Comment: @Quentin i agree with, but i don't understand what is wrong with my code, and negative point to it

Comment: @alifallahi — Your code stops the code in the question from working. It makes the problem worse.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing it.
1) create a hidden element and set your variable from your first script to attribute of that element.
This is your hidden element

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenVar"/>
```

and can set it in javascript as

```
document.getElementById("hiddenVar").setAttribute("myAttr",test)
```

Now you can get it in next script as

```
document.getElementById("hiddenVar").getAttribute("myAttr")
```

2) By .data() you can read about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Shoving things in DOM is a massively over complicated approach to this problem. Simply using a variable will work fine … and **does** in the code provided in the question. Anything that would break the approach the question is using would be likely to break the DOM approach too.

Comment: hidden input field looks bad for me and I don't really want to use this.. for 2) .data() I will take a look.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `window`'s global variables may be what some are looking to do. You can read more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349232/whats-the-difference-between-a-global-variable-and-a-window-variable-in-javas), or [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/windowhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window).

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.test = 'some text';
</script>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(window.test);
</script>
...
<script type="text/babel">
  alert(window.test);
</script>
```