# addEventListener() as a global function

Tags: javascript, dom

I just caught up in a confusion.
if suppose I implement `addEventListener()` as a global function (unlike as a method of some specific node like `node.addEventListener()` ) then does it act just like a usual global function or something goes under the hood while executing the code ending up becoming a method of some specific node

Note: DOM level 2, which defined the addEVentListener, stipulates that handler gets registered to the node. so which node is it registered to; window object is not a node

Comment: Yes, `addEventListener` is a native method that is prototyped on every EventListener-compatible object, creating a global function with the same name makes no difference

Comment: @adeneo but DOM level 2, which defined the addEVentListener, stipulates that handler gets registered to the node. so which node is it registered to; window object is not a node

Comment: The window object represents a window containing a DOM document, it's not a "node" per se, but the spec says that the event target that `addEventListener` is attached to may be an Element in a document, the Document itself, a **Window**, or any other object that supports events *(such as XMLHttpRequest)*.

Comment: Oops thankx for bringing this into the light that event target can be `Window`, but still there remains something.. event target can be `Window` but what would be the currentTarget (base) on which the handler is assigned (registered)

Answer (score 7):

It will applies to the global object `window` (which have the function `addEventListener`). Because:

```js
var a = 5;

console.log(a);
console.log(window.a);
```

Thus:

```
addEventListener( ... );
```

is the exact same things if you use:

```
window.addEventListener( ... );
```

Comment: That mean basically the DOM event listener operates on the window object as a base object. is it?

Comment: Yes. Any global variables and functions get attached to the `window`. When calling those function or using those variables, you either use `window.theGlobalVariableOrFunction` or just `theGlobalVariableOfFunction`, in which case the `window` is the base object.

Comment: If you open your log your `window` object, you'll get the properties of `window` plus all the global vars and functions. Try it!

Comment: Yes I know that window is the global object associated with the global execution context. But addEventListener was defined by DOM level 2 and it states that the handler get registered to a specific node when the handler is executed and `window` object is not a node. So how shall i reconcile it?

Comment: @Andrew The `window` object [**inherits from EventTarget**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) which implements the event listening functions and events. Whether or not the `window` is a node has no relevance. It inherits from [**EventTarget**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) so it has a `addEvenetListener`.

Comment: well window is itself the only global object, then how come it inherits from something. can you please mention any link which can redirect me to somewhere where this is well explained

Comment: @Andrew `window` (with lowercase `w`) is just an instance of a class (`Window` with uppercase `W`). The class chain of inheritance has no relation to wether the instance be global or not. JS just declare a new instance of the object and use it as a global one.

Comment: @Andrew http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679635/is-window-really-global-in-javascript And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349232/whats-the-difference-between-a-global-var-and-a-window-variable-in-javascript

Comment: I think I need a little elaborated illustration on your this mentioned context

Comment: @Andrew The picture in this [**article**](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_07.htm) is perfect. `window` beign the global object means that it is the last object in the scope chain (the darkest gray rect in the picture).

Comment: @Andrew JS will start looking at the scope object of the currently executed function, if not it will look at the scope object of the container of the currently executed function ... and so on untill the variable is found or untill the last scope object (`window`) is reached, at which point either the value is returned (if found) or `undefined` if not. The same goes for declaring variables and defining functions, if no `var` is met, then the variable will be attached the last scope in the scope chain (the `window`).

Comment: @Andrew When calling `addEventListener` inside a function, then we look up in that functions scope (if for example we defined a function inside that function called `addEvenetListener` then this one will be used). If not the search will buble up untill it's found (defined in some scope) or untill the last scope is reached (the `window`). Since `window` has the function `addEvenetListener` then that one will be used.

Comment: yeah i got what you just stated about the scope chain and execution context. Btw also when i run "event.currentTarget" it gives the output `undefined`, so on what (node or any base) the event was fired? And also, as you stated if it goes `window.eventListener` under the hood, then `event.currentTarget` should yell the output `window`

Comment: @Andrew Are you sure? I've just tested and it's working.

Comment: Oops just a min, i think i did some mistake

Comment: **with** `window.` https://jsfiddle.net/od1yn2zf/ and **without** `window.` https://jsfiddle.net/v9y8sw4L/

Comment: No mistake was done. actually in chrome console an error is popping up with a note that `currentTarget is not defined` . what output you are getting in chrome console

Comment: Did the `alert` pop up?

Comment: Nope not the window alert box, its the real error in chrome console
---> `Uncaught ReferenceError: currentTarget is not defined`

Comment: no i am runnning my code in google chrome and ide being the sublime. i wrote the code in sublime and run it in google chrome. and in google chrome developer console i am gettin that error about `currentTarget`

Comment: @Andrew With no idea how your code looks I can't say where the problem exactly is. Can you make a fiddle of your code? And take a look at my fiddles, and check if it's working for you.

Comment: i am not yet exposed to fiddle. Let me try it. can we share the same fiddle in collaborative way?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I don't know much about jsFiddle.

Comment: @Andrew we can colaborate. Go here: https://jsfiddle.net/v9y8sw4L/#&togetherjs=DekLT4fTjV

Comment: i'm getting some issue, may be becaue i'm new to fiddle. Btw its more reliable in the context of precision, to check the code in the real browser. try to run your code with 'alert(event.currentTarget)' and check whether the alert pops up or not. If not, check the console you ll see the error. 
and let the event handler be global function without `window.`

Comment: are you on skype or something convenient platform?

Comment: @Andrew is that you on jsFiddle or is it someone else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142352/discussion-between-andrew-and-ibrahim-mahrir).