# How Ember does Ember.version() from browser console?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I was studying Javascript / Ember and I was looking into its source codes.
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/

While I was studying, I found something interesting and I wonder how it works. As you may know, you can get version number of Ember if you type Ember.VERSION in the browser console. I wanted to do in my project so I started searching codes how Ember did it.

I could find

```
// in packages/ember/lib/index.js
Ember.VERSION = VERSION;
...
// Later exports Ember object
```

However I can't find how Ember makes it available in window (from browser). I expected they did like... window['Ember'] = Ember or something like that but I couldn't find any similar codes.

I wonder if there is anyone knows how they make Ember object available throughout window. Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a global var and a window.variable in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349232/whats-the-difference-between-a-global-var-and-a-window-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: @Siguza Thank you for the comment :)  But I am not sure why this is a possible duplicate... I know what is window and its variable. I just want to know how Ember "assigns" variable to window, since I couldn't find any relevant codes from their source codes.

Comment: Have you _read_ that question and its answer(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*ember-cli-app-version*](https://github.com/EmberSherpa/ember-cli-app-version) addon can expose your application's name and version info. So you can put your version in your templates via [an helper](https://github.com/EmberSherpa/ember-cli-app-version#app-version-helper).

The addon also registers the infos to the `Ember.libraries` so that *ember-inspector* can understand. You can access the `Ember.libraries` in a such way:

```
Ember.libraries._registry.filter(item=>{return item.name==='my-app-name';})[0].version
```

The addon can give you both `package.json` information or `git describe` result.