# why javascript can understand the variable out of function and loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't think my question duplicate with [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

In orther language(C#) i see, a variable declare
in a function or loop, When you out of function or loop they can't access variable has been declare in other function, but in javascript can.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        Text();
        Tex2();
    });
    function Text() {
        for (xxi = 0; xxi < 10; xxi++) {
            console.log(xxi);
            iix = 99;
        }
        console.log(xxi + iix);
        Tex2();
    }
    function Tex2() {
        console.log("What the hel:" + (xxi + iix));
    }
```

The result is:

[image]
Is there anyone can explain detail for me? thanks.

Comment: `iix = 99;` there's no declaration ... it's as if you had `window.iix = 99` ... and any reference to `iix` is like `window.iix` ... so, it works - to learn more, search for javascript scope chain - also, Tex2 is called once at the end of Tex1 and again in the document.ready

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript/500459#500459 gives a good rundown of scoping in JavaScript.

Comment: One thing that answer doesn't mention, @DocMax  is why `iix` in this case is global

Comment: If you declare a variable without a keyword, it becomes a global variable. `a=1` is global but `var a = 1` or `let a = 1` are not. Though, javascript also uses scope chaining, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: @Araymer - scope chaining is probably relevant to how `iix` and `xxi` are "visible" to Tex2 :p (I just realised BOTH iix and xxi are global :p)

Comment: @JaromandaX, Good point. I was hesitant to propose that this question was a duplicate of the other. Now I am very glad that I did not.

Comment: Thanks, I has been tested, but out of  lop no error. I has been test var xxi in for loop. Can you details for me?

Comment: @HồngVănVít Check the changed answer with clearer snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring them as global variables without using `var` keyword. Use the `var` keyword to scope them to their intended scope or use `"use strict"` on top of javascript file. You can also use `let` keyword to scope them to their very local scope.

1. Variables declared not using [var and let keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let%60) have global scope.
2. Variables declared using var keyword are treated by javascript as first statement inside their closed scope or function. So, it defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.
3. let keyword allows to declare variables limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used.

> I have created 3 snippets below. one with `let` keyword, one with `var` keyword, and one with `use strict` keyword over your code. Run to see changing behavior of same code piece.

**SNIPPETS BELOW**

> `let` keyword snippet. Run to see that variable is not available outside block scope even.
>
> ```js
> //let keyword snippet. See variable is not available outside block scope even.
>
> $(document).ready(function () {
>         Text();
>         Tex2();
>     });
>     function Text() {
>         for (let xxi = 0; xxi < 10; xxi++) {
>             console.log(xxi);
>            let iix = 99;
>         }
>         var xyz; 
>         try
>         {
>           xyz = xxi + iix;
>         } 
>         catch (e){
>           xyz = e;
>         }
>         console.log(xyz);
>         Tex2();
>     }
>     function Tex2() {
>     var abc;
>      try
>      {
>       abc = (xxi + iix);
>      } 
>      catch (e){
>         abc = e;
>       }
>         console.log("What the hel:" + abc);
>     }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> `var` keyword snippet. Run to see that variable is not available outside function scope.
>
> ```js
> //var keyword snippet. See variable is not available outside function scope.
>
> $(document).ready(function () {
>         Text();
>         Tex2();
>     });
>     function Text() {
>         for (var xxi = 0; xxi < 10; xxi++) {
>             console.log(xxi);
>            var iix = 99;
>         }
>         var xyz; 
>         try
>         {
>           xyz = xxi + iix;
>         } 
>         catch (e){
>           xyz = e;
>         }
>         console.log(xyz);
>         Tex2();
>     }
>     function Tex2() {
>     var abc;
>      try
>      {
>       abc = (xxi + iix);
>      } 
>      catch (e){
>         abc = e;
>       }
>         console.log("What the hel:" + abc);
>     }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```

> `use strict` keyword snippet. Run to see that it will not run at all. This is your code with use strict.

```js
//Your snippet with "use strict". Will not work at all.
"use strict"

$(document).ready(function () {
        Text();
        Tex2();
    });
    function Text() {
        for (xxi = 0; xxi < 10; xxi++) {
            console.log(xxi);
            iix = 99;
        }
        console.log(xxi + iix);
        Tex2();
    }
    function Tex2() {
        console.log("What the hel:" + (xxi + iix));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variable, otherwise the scope will be the same as window.iix. The below snippet has the result you expect (an error).

I've changed the line  `for (xxi = 0; xxi < 10; xxi++) {` to  for `(var xxi = 0; xxi < 10; xxi++) {`

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        Text();
        Tex2();
    });
    function Text() {
     
        for (var xxi = 0; xxi < 10; xxi++) {
            console.log(xxi);
            iix = 99;
        }
        console.log(xxi + iix);
        Tex2();
    }
    function Tex2() {
        console.log("What the hel:" + (xxi + iix));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I has been test, but out of  lop no error. It have error out of function. Can you detail detail

Answer (score 1):

When you don't use `var` to declare a variable, it's understand as a global variable.
What happened in your code won't happen again if you use `var` or `let` every time you declare a variable.

Comment: Thanks, I has been test, but out of  lop no error. I has been test var xxi in for loop. Can you detail detail ?

Comment: Try refreshing your console or run your code on another window's console. Your two variables should be declared with var keyword. After that if you run it it will throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

Any variable which is not declared inside a function, is treated as a window variable:

```
    for (xxi = 0; xxi < 10; xxi++) {
        console.log(xxi); // this variable
        iix = 99; // this variable
    }
```

If you had done this, javascript won't read the variable outside the scope:

```
    for (var xxi = 0; xxi < 10; xxi++) {
        console.log(xxi);
        var iix = 99;
    }
```

Explained (Let's understand using declarations instead of looking for errors):

```
    var xxi = "one"; //global variable
    var iix = "two"; //global variable
    globalVar = "three"; // window variable i.e. window.globalVar
    var getValues = function () {
         var xxi; //local variable for the scope 
         var iix; //local variable for the scope 
         for (xxi = 0; xxi < 10; xxi++) {
            console.log(xxi); // takes the local variable
            iix = 99; //local change of value
         }
         globalVar = 100; //change of value to window variable accessible inside
    };
    getValues();
    var seeValues = function () {
        console.log(xxi); //"one" //Displays the value of global because the local variable of getValues() is not accessible outside
        console.log(iix); //"two" //Same as above
        console.log(globalVar); //100 and not "three" //Displays the altered window variable
    };
    seeValues();
```

See this link for detailed information: http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/javascript/understanding-local-and-global-variables-in-javascript and [What's the difference between a global var and a window.variable in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349232/whats-the-difference-between-a-global-var-and-a-window-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, I has been test, but out of lop no error. I has been test var xxi in for loop. Can you explain more detail ?

Comment: See the detailed explanation in the edit. please tick the answer if you find it helpful :)