# Python, With Selenium how to add a JS function to the page?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to add some JS functions to a page but not sure how do it without assigning the function to the window object.

The following will work:

```
driver.execute_script("console.log('lalala');")
driver.execute_script("function momo(){console.log('lalala')};momo();")
```

But trying to do:

```
driver.execute_script("function momo(){console.log('lalala')};")
driver.execute_script("momo();")
```

will fail:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: momo is not defined
```

I know assigning the function to the window:

```
driver.execute_script("window.momo = function(){console.log('lalala')};")
```

will solve the issue, but maybe there is another way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Adding the function to window is an elegant solution. Is there a specific issue that you're having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this answers the question:

```
driver.execute_script("window.momo = () => console.log('lalala');")
```

I'm just rewriting that in a more modern syntax.

Comment: this is the same function as in the question. but much more elegant... I still think there is no way to avoid using `window` in the script

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can create `script` element

```
driver.execute_script("""
(function(){
    s = document.createElement('script');
    s.textContent = 'function momo(){console.log("lalala")};';
    document.body.appendChild(s);
})();
""")
driver.execute_script("momo();")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to introduce a new element to the window dom hence the error:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: momo is not defined

Your solution is probably the only one unless you try to manipulate an existing element!

In other words, you can add a JS function to any element that is already on the page.

This is the idea of the scope of the window dom.

You can understand more by reading this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6349260/8179099).